# What is Spring Cloud Config Server consistent model？

Tags: distributed-system, spring-cloud-config-server, configserver

Config Server I can choose zk, etcd,  spring cloud config server, hashicrop consul. zk,etcd,consul is strong consistency. what is spring cloud config server consistent model? How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Config Server uses Git as its [default backend](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_git_backend). The documentation states that Config Server supports the following additional backends:

- [File system backend](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_file_system_backend)
- [HashiCorp Vault backend](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#vault-backend)
- [JDBC backend](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_jdbc_backend)
- [CredHub backend](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_credhub_backend)

The aforementioned links describe each backend in more detail, as well as configuration instructions.

Comment: thanks！Very useful。